# How to avoid stackoverflow while calling methods of two classes in eachother Java

Tags: java, android, stack-overflow

I searched the whole StackOverflow website I come across only one nearest 
answer but not working in my condition.

How can I call methods of two classes in each other

First Class is Alpha and calling a Function of Beta

```
public Class Alpha
    {
       Beta obj;

   public Alpha()
   {
       obj = new Beta();
   }
   public void A()
   {
      print A;
      obj.B();
   }
}
```

Second Class is Beta and calling a function of Alpha

```
public Class Beta
{
   Alpha obj;

   public Beta()
   {
       obj = new Alpha();
   }
   public void B()
   {
      print B;
      obj.A()
   }
}
```

In Java/android, it shows StackOverflow exception. Due to the recursive call of constructors of each other.

How to avoid this Exception?

I have 15 Classes and each one is linked Cyclically.

Do I need to use parent class?

Or How I should use constructors to avoid StackOverflow Exception?

Comment: Its `class`.  And break the instantiation of one of the class in another's constructor.

Comment: Why are they circularly linked?

Comment: Remove the cross-calls to each classes constructor. Now the invocation stack builds up until it overflows.

Comment: @AndrewLi it's just an example to solve the problem. The database is using the functions of Scanning Class and Scanning is using the function of Database class.

Comment: This is an example of recursion.  The best way to avoid recursion is, dont use recursion.

Comment: This is obviously going to cause a `StackOverflowError` unless there's some break clause, but to echo @AndrewLi, why are you doing this anyway?

Comment: this is not natural project (BTW dont compile). In reality recurrency must be broken at some reason)

Comment: In any case, you shouldn't be instantiating dependencies in constructors; use dependency injection instead.

Comment: "I have 15 Classes and each one is linked Cyclically."
That might be your problem.

Comment: Okay Okay, I got it thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggestion that will break the cycle: Specify one class as the parent and the other as the dependent.

Let's put Alpha in charge:

```
public class Alpha {

   private Beta beta;

   public Alpha() {
       this.beta = new Beta(this);
   }
}
```

Here's the child Beta:

```
public class Beta {

   private Alpha alpha;

   public Beta(Alpha parent) {
       this.alpha = parent;
   }
}
```

No more cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You shall change your class `Beta`'s definition to break the circular link between the two classes and creating their instances. It could be somewhat like this instead:

```
public class Beta {
   Alpha obj;

   public Beta() {
   }

   public void B() {
      print B;
      new Alpha().A();
   }
}
```

Ideally, you shall not create instances of other classes unless you would want to access them.

Comment: It's correct, but  `new Alpha().A();` needs to be called in every method.

Comment: @UmairSajidMinhas Are you trying to call a static method in that case? Or probably make a call from one method inside Beta and then use that private method within Beta class to replace all such definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The stack overflow is obvious; it's not just that the class definitions are cyclical; the constructors are recursive.  The recursion is just "hidden" because they are in different classes.  With any recursion, there must be some limit condition to break the recursion cycle.  Without knowing the details of your problem -- why do you have this cyclical definition -- it's hard to give a solution.  It really comes down to a question of code architecture.  I can offer a few suggestions.

First, I generally dislike cyclical definitions.  It leads to confusion and issues in doing code builds and ports.  This can be avoided by using interfaces; maybe an empty marker interface.  I would then take assignment of the internal objects out of the constructor, and make an explicit set() function, so that the caller has to initialize these:

```
public interface SomeInterface {  }

public class Alpha implements SomeInterface
{ 
   private SomeInterface obj; 
   public Alpha()
   {}

   public void setBeta (SomeInterface si)
   {
     obj = si;
   } 
}

public class Beta implements SomeInterface
{ 
  private SomeInterface obj;
  public Beta () 
  { }

  public void setAlpha ( SomeInterface si )
  {
    obj = si;
  }
}
```

In the calling code, you would have

```
Alpha a = new Alpha();
a.setBeta ( new Beta() );
```